# jhipster - error executing task :bower

Tags: bower, jhipster

I am having an issue building my app based off jhipster, using gradle. It fails on task :bower. The exact error I get is:

```
./gradlew bower --debug

20:23:46.154 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':bower'.
20:23:46.174 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process 'command 'node''. Working directory: /workplace/zupus Command: node /workplace/zupus/node_modules/bower/bin/bower install
20:23:46.174 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Environment for process 'command 'node'':     {PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jav    a-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin,     CMD_DURATION=7.19s, XAUTHORITY=/home/brendan/.Xauthority, __fish_help_dir=/usr/share/doc/fish, XMODIFIERS=@im=i    bus, XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/,     GDMSESSION=ubuntu, MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path, TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/, GTK    _IM_MODULE=ibus, DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-2jqL9U4Ofh,     DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path, XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity, SSH_AGENT_PID=2238, COLORTERM=gn    ome-terminal, QT4_IM_MODULE=xim, UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/ups    tart-    session/1000/2169, SESSION_MANAGER=local/brendan-home:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2337,unix/brendan-home:/tmp/.ICE-unix/233    7, LOGNAME=brendan, JOB=dbus, PWD=/workplace/zupus, IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1,     DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db, LANGUAGE=en_US, WINDOWID=75497483, SHELL=/usr/bin/fish, __fish_bin_di    r=/usr/bin, INSTANCE=, J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle, OLDPWD=/wor    kplace/zupus,     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated, J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre, GTK_MODULES=overlay-scroll    bar:unity-gtk-module, CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim, TEXTDOMAIN=im-config,     XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0, COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/, SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session    ,     LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:    sg    =30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.    taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;3    1:    *.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.    deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpi    o=    01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=    01;35:*.    pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.sv    gz    =01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.m    kv=01;35:*    .webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.a    sf    =01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl    =01;35:*.    dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=    01    ;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=    00;36:*.    mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:, SSH_AGENT_LAUNC    HE    R=upstart, SHLVL=1, __fish_sysconfdir=/etc/fish, COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu,     QT_IM_MODULE=ibus, JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle, TERM=xterm, XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt    ,     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg, LANG=en_US    .UTF-8,     XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0, GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-k4czcd, XDG_S    ES    SION_ID=c2, SELINUX_INIT=YES, DISPLAY=:0,     NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript, GDM_LANG=en_US, UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1, XDG_    GR    EETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/brend    an, DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu,     GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-k4czcd/gpg:0:1, SESSION=ubuntu, USER=brendan, XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-, VTE    _V    ERSION=3409, XDG_SEAT=seat0, SSH_AUTH_SOCK    =/run/user/1000/keyring-k4czcd/ssh,     NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat, QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5, XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000, XDG_VT    NR    =7, HOME=/home/brendan, __fish_datadir=/us    r/share/fish, GNOME_KEYRING_PID=2165    }
20:23:46.175 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING    
20:23:46.175 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process start    ed: command 'node'.
20:23:46.179 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTED    
20:23:46.179 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams are h    a    ndled...
20:23:46.179 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started proces    s     'command 'node''
20:23:46.187 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED    
20:23:46.188 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'node''     fi    nished with exit value 1 (state: FAILED)
20:23:46.188 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] F    in    ished executing task ':bower'
20:23:46.188 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :bower FAILED    
20:23:46.189 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor]     :bower (Thread[mai    n,5,main]) completed. Took 0.036 secs.
20:23:46.189 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor    ] Task worker [Thre    ad[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.899 secs, idle: 0.001 secs
20:23:46.194 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     
20:23:46.194 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception    .
20:23:46.194 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     
20:23:46.194 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     * What went wrong:    
20:23:46.194 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     Execution failed for task ':bower'.    
20:23:46.195 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     > Process 'command 'node'' finished     wit    h non-zero exit value 1
20:23:46.195 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     
20:23:46.195 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     * Try:    
20:23:46.195 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     Run with --stacktrace option to get the     stack trace. 
20:23:46.195 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]     
20:23:46.196 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]     BUILD FAILED    
20:23:46.196 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]     
20:23:46.197 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 3.275 secs
```

I have a feeling it has to do with global vs local npm installs, but I'm scratching my head about how to fix it or even find the error. I'm hoping someone else can save me from more hours of frustration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this eventually, if anyone else stumbles across this the answer was that I had to uninstall node (i.e. sudo apt-get remove node) and leave nodejs in place. You should see this:

```
user@user /w/zupus> which node
/usr/bin/node
user@user /w/zupus> which nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my quick and dirty fix on Mac OS:

I just ran npm install bower as sudo

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

Answer (score 0):

I used windows 7 and got this error. I was able to fix this issue by installing Git. Make sure that you close the current command prompt window and try again.

Answer (score 0):

just do `npm install bower` in project root directory where **bower.json** file should present.